# ImageView Fill Remaining Space

Tags: android

I'm creating layout with ImageView and HorizontalScrollView. It looks like the image below.. [image]

when the user click one of the image at HorizontalScrollView it will display bigger image at ImageView..

so far my code is below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

    <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/mainHorizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/orange"
                >

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic1"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    ></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image2"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic2"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    ></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

above code make the ImageView fill the entire screen..what i want is the ImageView fill the remaining screen that not filled by the HorizontalScrollView.. How to do this??

Comment: Use weightsum and layout_weights in your layout. Also use a linear layout as the parent layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `ImageView` to be:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageViewTop"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight=1
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
/>
```

And make the parent View a `LinearLayout`

Comment: and also need to set the parentview as vertical orientation.

Answer (score 0):

change the parent layout to LinearLayout and add use weights on ImageView and child RelativeLayout as follows,

```
<LinearLayout ....
......>
<ImagView layout-weight="1"...
...../>
<RelativeLayout layout-weight="0.6"..
......>
<!-- child Views -->
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Change the values of weight according your requirement, hope this helps